# VBA excel row copying method doesn't work

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy one row to an other workbook (only if there is a match) and i can accomplish that with a simple loop but i would like to use some better and possibly quicker method:

```
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(FROM)
Set wskz = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set wbi = Workbooks.Open(TO)
Set wski = wbi.Worksheets("Sheet1")         


si = 5
Do While wski.Cells(si, 1).Text <> "END"       ' loop through the values in column "A" in the "TO" workbook
    varver = wski.Cells(si, 1).Text            ' data to look up
    s = 5
    Do While wskz.Cells(s, 1).Text <> "END"       ' table where we search for the data in the "FROM" workbook
        If wskz.Cells(s, 1).Text = varver Then Exit Do
        s = s + 1
    Loop

    If wskz.Cells(s, 1).Text <> "END" Then  
    ' I am trying this copy method to replace the loop but it throws an error
       wskz.Range(Cells(s, 1), Cells(s, 250)).Copy Destination:=wski.Range(Cells(si, 1), Cells(si, 250))

    ' this is the working loop:
        'For i = 1 To 250
              '  wskz.Cells(s, i) = wski.Cells(si, i)
               ' i = i + 1
            'End If
        'Next i
```

[image]

The problem with the new copying method throws an error as it can be seen above.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: As mentioned in the answers, the reason is most likely because whilst you set the worksheet for the Range, you didn't tell it which worksheet the `.Cells()` are on. Just add `wskz.` and `wski.` before `.cells()`, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do exactly what you are looking for:

```
Sub test()

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  Dim SourceWS As Worksheet, DestWS As Worksheet

  Set SourceWS = Workbooks.Open("FROM").Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Set DestWS = Workbooks.Open("TO").Worksheets("Sheet1")

  Dim runner As Variant, holder As Range

  If IsError(Application.Match("END", DestWS.Range("A5:A" & Rows.Count), 0)) Or IsError(Application.Match("END", SourceWS.Range("A5:A" & Rows.Count), 0)) Then
    SourceWS.Parent.Close False
    DestWS.Parent.Close False
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Set holder = DestWS.Range("A5:A" & Application.Match("END", DestWS.Range("A5:A" & Rows.Count), 0) + 3)

  For Each runner In SourceWS.Range("A5:A" & Application.Match("END", SourceWS.Range("A5:A" & Rows.Count), 0) + 3)
    If IsNumeric(Application.Match(runner.Value, holder, 0)) Then runner.EntireRow.Copy DestWS.Rows(Application.Match(runner.Value, holder, 0) + 4)
  Next

  SourceWS.Parent.Close True
  DestWS.Parent.Close True

  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

It is self-explaining to my eye, but if you have any questions, just ask :)

Comment: Manu's solution works, but as soon as I'll have time I am going to try this to see if it's faster than the current two loops solution. Thank you!

Comment: For some reason this code throws an object error:Application.Match("END", SourceWS.Range("A5:A" & Rows.Count), 0)    but i replaced it with a "long" lastRow = SourceWS.Cells(SourceWS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row  and modified the For loop : For Each runner In SourceWS.Range("A5:A" & lastRow)  Now it works and much faster than the original one

Comment: If you are able to improve it, then that is better than any answer you simply copy/paste :D

Comment: The error may be cus there is no "END" found... I assumed there is data below your "END" you did not want to parse... (just as a response to your error)

Comment: :I have only one question regarding the code: when you set the holder :Set holder = DestWS.Range("A5:A" & Application.Match("VÉGE", DestWS.Range("A5:A" & Rows.Count), 0) + 3)  why did you add 3 to the "MATCH" result?

Comment: Error: there is an "END" I copy pasted it  to ensure that it would be the same format and everything

Comment: I also tested it and it worked.. the offset (+3) is because the MATCH starts at row 5. If row 10 is "END" then "6" is returned. But we need row 9 so we simply add 3 :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace :

```
wskz.Range(Cells(s, 1), Cells(s, 250)).Copy Destination:=wski.Range(Cells(si, 1), Cells(si, 250))
```

by

```
wskz.Range(wskz.Cells(s, 1), wskz.Cells(s, 250)).Copy Destination:=wski.Range(wski.Cells(si, 1), wski.Cells(si, 250))
```

Or by :

```
Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range

Set Rng1 = wskz.Range(wskz.Cells(s, 1), wskz.Cells(s, 250))
Set Rng2 = wski.Range(wski.Cells(si, 1), wski.Cells(si, 250))

Rng1.Copy Rng2
```

Answer (score 1):

This Error often occures related to Copy-Methods. I also ran into this kind of Error when I had my Sub on Worksheet Level. Try to extract it to a seperate Modul.
Also it seems your references to the `Cells` are broken. You can find this explained in the docs for `Range.Item`.
Try this

```
With wskz
    .Range(.Cells(s, 1), .Cells(s, 250)).Copy 
End With
```